# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I am getting `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

Scanner only works one time (the first loop).

The full stack trace is:

> Exception in thread "main"
>
> ```
> java.util.NoSuchElementException at
>
> java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) at
>
> java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
> ```

Could you please help me fix my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer;
        do
        {
            input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
            System.out.println("- Start a new Game (S)");
            System.out.println("- Exit (E)");
            System.out.println("Please enter your choice: ");

            answer = input.next();

            if (answer.equals("s") || answer.equals("S"))
            {
                Hangman h1 = new Hangman();
                h1.getWord();
                h1.printData();
                h1.CountTheLetters();
                h1.GiveTheLetters();
            }
        } while (!answer.equals("e") && !answer.equals("E"));
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Thank you for the game");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to re-create a new scanner object each time you read from it.

Comment: input = new Scanner(System.in); ? this? ok i delete it. the same error

Answer (score 0):

try instantiating Scanner object inside the do-while loop instead of instantiating it in the main function..

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work on Eclipse,are you using any online IDE like Ideone,because online IDE's take input only once like all input only once so there is a runtime error I would suggest you to run your code on eclipse If that doesn't seem to work do something as I have done below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;



public class Main {
    public static void funct(Scanner input){

        System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
         System.out.println("- Start a new Game (S)");
        System.out.println("- Exit (E)");
        System.out.println("Please enter your choice: ");
        String answer = input.next();

         if(answer.equals("e")||answer.equals("E")){
            System.out.println("Thank You For the Game");
         }
         else{
            funct(input);
         }

    }
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    funct(input);

 }
}
```

Comment: when i copy paste your code the menu is running. i put the answer and then again the menu and again the answer but when i put this ( else{
            Hangman h1 = new Hangman();
     h1.getWord();
     h1.printData();
     h1.CountTheLetters();
     h1.GiveTheLetters();

             funct(input);
           )

Comment: it collapse and then i get the same error. Is it possible to have an error in hangman? The first time is running good!

Comment: It's running fine on eclipse don't use online ide's for this as described above